# javascript Timer How to set up

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm new to javascript and i'm doing a project "building a memory game".

I got stuck while I was trying to set up a timer that starts working when a card is clicked and reset the time when the game is restarted, Besides that I want it to save the best time and every time to compare between the times and show it in the page as the BEST TIME.
Here is how it is built so far 
Thanks to the helpers:)
Much appreciated

```js
// Those are global variables, they stay alive and reflect the state of the game


var elPreviousCard = null;
var flippedCouplesCount = 0;
var userName;
var currentlyFlipped = 0;
// This is a constant that we dont change during the game (we mark those with CAPITAL letters)
var TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT = 8;

// Load an audio file
var audioWin = new Audio('sound/win.mp3');
var audiowrong = new Audio('sound/wrong.mp3') ;
var audioright = new Audio ('sound/right.mp3') ;




toggle_visibility("restartBtn");
getUsername();

function getUsername(){
    var savedUserName = localStorage.getItem("savedUserName");
    if(!savedUserName){
        var userName = prompt("What is your username?"); 
        localStorage.setItem("savedUserName", userName );
        alert("Welcome "+ userName);
    }
    else{
        alert("Welcome "+ savedUserName);
    }
    setNameOnPage(savedUserName);
}

function getNewUsername(){
    var newUserName = prompt("What is your username?"); 
        localStorage.setItem("savedUserName", newUserName);
        setNameOnPage(savedUserName);
        alert("Welcome "+ newUserName);
}

function setNameOnPage(uName){
    document.querySelector("h4.user").innerHTML = "Good Luck " + uName;
}

// This function is called whenever the user click a card
function cardClicked(elCard) {
    // If the user clicked an already flipped card - do nothing and return from the function
    if (elCard.classList.contains('flipped')) {
        return;
    }
    if (currentlyFlipped>=2) {
        return;
    }
    // Flip it
    elCard.classList.add('flipped');
    currentlyFlipped++;
    // This is a first card, only keep it in the global variable
    if (elPreviousCard === null) {
        elPreviousCard = elCard;
    } else {
        // get the data-card attribute's value from both cards
        var card1 = elPreviousCard.getAttribute('data-card');
        var card2 = elCard.getAttribute('data-card');

        // No match, schedule to flip them back in 1 second
        if (card1 !== card2){
           setTimeout(function () {
                elCard.classList.remove('flipped');
                elPreviousCard.classList.remove('flipped');
                elPreviousCard = null;
                currentlyFlipped=0;
                audiowrong.play();
            }, 1000)  
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Yes! a match!
                flippedCouplesCount++;
                elPreviousCard = null;
                currentlyFlipped=0;
                audioright.play();
            }, 500) 

            // All cards flipped!
            if (TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT === flippedCouplesCount) {
                toggle_visibility("restartBtn");
                audioWin.play();
            }
        }
    }
}

function restartGame(){
    //  get  all  divs  in  the  document
    var  cards = document.querySelectorAll('div.card');
    for  (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
    {
        cards[i].classList.remove('flipped');
    }
}
        
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!e.style.display || e.style.display == 'block'){
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
       e.style.display = null;
 }
```

```css
.header {
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid darkcyan;
    color:darkcyan;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
      
}

.header img {
    float:right;
   

}

.card {
    background-color: pink;
    height: 165px;
    width: 165px;    
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    

}
.card:hover {
    background-color: yellow; 
    transform: scale(1.08); 
}



.card img {
    position: absolute;
}

.flipped .back {
    display: none;
}
body {
    background-color: aqua;
}
button {
    background: rgb(223, 117, 20);
    width: 170px;
    height: 95px;
}

 button:hover {
background-color: purple;
}
 
.timer {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/game.css" />
  <button onclick="getNewUsername()">Change User</button>
  <button id="restartBtn" onclick="restartGame()">Restart</button>
  <p>Completion time: <span class="timer" id="timer">0:00</span></p>

</head>


<body>

  <div class="header">
    <img src="img/layout/logo.png">
    <h1>Memory Monsters</h1>
    <h4 class="user"></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card"   data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/1.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/7.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/1.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/7.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="5" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/5.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="5" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/5.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="2" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/2.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div><div class="card" data-card="2" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/2.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div><div class="card" data-card="3" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/3.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="3" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/3.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="4" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/4.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="4" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
      <img src="img/cards/4.png">
      <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="6" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/6.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div><div class="card" data-card="8" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/8.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div><div class="card" data-card="6" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/6.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div><div class="card" data-card="8" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/8.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">

    
<script src="js/game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The actual countdown timer should be pretty simple since it looks like you already know how to use setTimeout.  You will need a variable that begins at 0 and then a set timeout function which increments the variable every second.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right if your goal is to get the time difference between the game is started and the game is finished successful?

Then just init a global variable

```
var start = new Date();
```

When the user finished successful

```
var end = new Date();
```

And the time difference is

```
var seconds = (start.getTime() - end.getTime()) / 1000;
```

If the game is restarted just renew start!

```
start = new Date();
```

I guess you don't need the "Yes! a match!"-timeout.

To save the best time you need a server sided storage of every user, JavaScript can't do that for you.